# android startActivity(intent) leads to 'source not found'

Tags: android

```
final Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse   ("http://kuikui.iteye.com"));

browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

if i change Uri.parse('http://kuikui.iteye.com') to Uri.parse('market://details?id=ifl.games.ToSee"). then it runs normally.what's the problem?
normal "market://details?id=if1.games.ToSee"
error  "http://kuikui.iteye.com" or any http:// alike intent tag.

Comment: Tried your code and it runs normally.

Comment: What do you mean "source not found"? Is it crashing? If so, please post a stack trace from logcat

Comment: Source not found,                                                               THe JAR file ..\androidADT\...\sdk\platforms\android-17\android.jar has no source attachment.you can attach the source by clicking Attach source below

Comment: I copy-paste the code and works perfectly. Are you getting same error for all "http://" sites?

Comment: yes,same error for all "http://"

Comment: there are no error trace at all in logcat.

Comment: The http intent filter is probably leading to a default http renderer that is not present. My guess

Comment: then what sould i do to solve this problem.